# How to include header file in IAR workbench studio?

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I have created group in IAR IDE and I have added the .h file, but still it is showing error like source file not found. How do I add header file in IAR?

[image: img]

I also tried adding path in preprocessor as $PROJ_DIR$/hdr. But still I'm getting same error.

Comment: It seems the file `cyt2b75cae.h` is a header file of the device CYT2B75CAE, then it would be resided in the folder of system include, and `system_cyt2b7.h` should be there too.

Answer (score 5):

> I have created group in IAR IDE and I have added the .h file, but still it is showing error like source file not found.

Adding header files to source tree is only for convenience. It won't help the compiler to find the header file. Also, the group name has no real correlation to any folder on disk.

> I also tried adding path in preprocessor as $PROJ_DIR$/hdr.

That won't work because IDE environment variables like `$PROJ_DIR$` are not recognized in the source code.

> How do I add header file in IAR?

Go to project options and add your path of your header folder in `C/C++ Compiler -> Preprocessor -> Additional include directories`. This will make sure that compiler scans the directory were your header is when including the file. You can use `$PROJ_DIR$` relative paths here.

Comment: `$PROJ_DIR$` is probably unnecessary. It is more portable perhaps to add `.\hdr` to the additional includes list, which will be relative to the project directory (assuming the project file and therefore the build root is in the project root).

Comment: @Clifford I suspect current path relative `.\hdr` might not work as expected if invoking build process from command line in directory other than where project file is. But since I haven't really done command line building myself, I cannot say for sure if that is the case or not.

Comment: I don't ;-).  I would expect the build/current working directory to be set to the project directory by the tool.  I have not use IAR in years, but that is what every other IDE (e.g. Keil, Visual Studio).  I have used does.   Equally I am not sure if IAR has the ability to output a makefile or batch file for builds outside the IDE, but if it does using absolute paths will cause portability problems.